# how to remove duplicate div ondrop

Tags: php, javascript, html, drag-and-drop, duplicates

I'm a newbie in javascript, so i need all your help.
So basically i'm trying to do ondrop function(validate), so when I drop something for the first time, the validate function will run and drop the div value from the php. But for the second time and so on, if I dropped the same div value I want it to alert duplicate and remove that div element(the duplicate), but I'm unsuccessfull in detecting the duplicate div.

Can anyone tell me whats wrong with my code?

I have a javascript, php, and html like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 function dragIt(target, e) {

 e.dataTransfer.setData('div', target.id);

return false;
}

function validate(target, e){

    var id = e.dataTransfer.getData('div');
    var clone = document.getElementById(id).cloneNode(true);
    var allValues = []; 
    for (i=0; i<clone.length; i++)
        {
         if (clone[i].value != "")
            {
             allValues[i] = clone[i].value.toLowerCase();
            }
        }
    allValues.sort();       
    var uniqueValues = [];      
    var idx = 0;
    var prevValue = allValues[0];
    var currValue = allValues[0];
    for (i=0; i<allValues.length; i++)
        { 
         currValue = allValues[i];
         if (currValue != prevValue){idx++;}
         uniqueValues[idx] = currValue;
         prevValue = currValue;
        }
    if (uniqueValues.length != allValues.length)
        {

          e.preventDefault();
          clone.parentNode.removeChild(clone);
         alert('Cannot submit duplicate entries');
         return false;
        }
    else    {
         alert(clone.id);
         e.preventDefault();
         target.appendChild(clone); 
         return true;
        }
}
```

Comment: Your PHP seems incomplete, can you add the rest of it here?

Comment: Hmm, it seems your validate function resets unique values, each time it is run: var uniqueValues = []; Maybe store it somewhere in your namespace?

Comment: Yup i just post the fixed version, thx for your help though, so basically i want to get the div id ="'.$fundcourseArray[$j]. drag it and drop it in the html but i want to remove any duplicate if we drag and drop the same div id the second time and so on, thx